# Python assign variable from command line or user input

Tags: python, input, python-import

I import fonts from a file with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# my_app.py

from fonts import \
  GREEK_FONT,\
  BASIC_LATIN_FONT,\
  VINCENT_FONT,\
  CP437_FONT,\
  SINCLAIRS_FONT,\
  LCD_FONT,\
  TINY_FONT\

  try:
      font = sys.argv[1]
      try:
          if font in dir():
              print font
```

On the command line I run:

```
./my_app.py CP437_FONT
```

Printed Output = CP437_FONT

If I add:

```
font=input("Name a font:") and user inputs CP437_FONT
```

Printed Output = CP437_FONT

But if I code in:

```
font = CP437_FONT
```

Printed Output is entire font tuple. What I need.

I need to assign the variable font the imported CP437_FONT from the command line.
How can I assign the font I need from user input?

The only work around I have is:

```
 font = sys.argv[5].lower()
 if font in ["cp437_font"]:
     font = CP437_FONT
```

Comment: `import fonts; if hasattr(fonts, font): font = getattr(fonts, font)`.

Comment: I modified it a little, but I don't know why it broke ```fonts```. ```from fonts import \
  GREEK_FONT,\
  BASIC_LATIN_FONT,\
  VINCENT_FONT,\
  CP437_FONT,\
  SINCLAIRS_FONT,\
  LCD_FONT,\
  TINY_FONT\
as fonts```

Comment: It doesn't work, because all you've done is create an alias for `TINY_FONT`. You need to import the `fonts` module itself so you can reference its attributes and use `hasattr/getattr` to access them. If you want to access them directly, use e.g. `fonts.GREEK_FONT`.

Comment: Hi ekhumoro, thanks for that clarification. However, I already have understood that. Sorry for my confusing reply. You answered question #1 correctly. Me not knowing that there would be a question #2, I need to ask now, "How do I import a specific def name from a file of several plus def names, or more so particular, how do I load those def's individually by name if say, I have 100 and only want 20? Maybe this requires me to submit a new question? Thanks for your help. I have researched it, but found and tried nothing functional. Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do it other than what you are already doing. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: It's mostly aesthetics. The user can choose a default font by setting a variable in the configuration or the user can choose the font with sys.argv[5] from command line. So I'm considering a way to keep the font names as simple as possible and I need a way to inform the user of the actual font names. Rather than just creating a list of names for the user to see, I'd add functionality by having import pull the individual names of the fonts. If I use ```from fonts import``` I can't use sys.argv[5] to use the font unless I ```if sys.argv[5] == GREEK_FONT: font = GREEK_FONT elsif sys.argv[5] ==```

Comment: import wont let me create a list of fonts and then do a ```for i in list_of_fonts: from fonts import i``` and I'm trying to keep it user friendly if the user decides to add any of their own fonts in the future....

Comment: I don't see why you need to import the individual font names at all. Just do `import fonts` as I suggested to begin with, and use attribute access. This also allows you to iterate over all the names in the module. Another way would be to create a class with specialised methods for managing the fonts, and then import a singleton instance of that class wherever its needed.

Comment: Thank you for all your help and helping me understand the intricacies of the Python import function. In a basic sense, it is so much less complicated for a command line user to use just simple font names as opposed to the user using font name plus attributes. Name.Attribute approach works just fine internally for the  script, but adding user input makes it messy. It would be so simple to ```create a list, for x the list, then  from file.py __import__("value of x")``` The user can "see" the list of fonts in the script, choose one for the default font and use the font names on the command line

Comment: I found something else that works, but I don't know that it resolves my problem. ``` font_updater = [ 'GREEK_FONT' : GREEK_FONT,  'BASIC_LATIN_FONT' : BASIC_LATIN_FONT,  'VINCENT_FONT' : VINCENT_FONT,  'CP437_FONT' : CP437_FONT,  'SINCLAIRS_FONT' : SINCLAIRS_FONT,  'LCD_FONT' : LCD_FONT,  'TINY_FONT' : TINY_FONT] font = font_updater[sys.argv[1]] ```

Comment: Why bother with all that, when you can simply do: `font = getattr(fonts, sys.argv[1])`?